# Can Not Open mmssms.db

Tags: sqlite

I have taken a copy of the mmssms.db from the /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/

I am trying to open this in sqliteman, but the database does not want to load in, I have taken multiple copies and it will still not open.

The Android version is Ice Cream Sandwhich.

Any help will be muchly appreciated as I am running out of ideas! All other databases open fine from the phone.

Comment: Any error messages? "Does not open" is a bit vague. What exactly does happen instead? Can you open it with the `sqlite` command line program?